# Como manipular listas con Phyton

Tags: python

Tengo que realizar un registro usando un RFID , entonces para facilitarme a mí el almacenamiento creé dos listas, por ejemplo (IDENTIFICADOR=[] y HORA=[]). A la hora de eliminar o dar de baja una tarjeta , tendría que eliminar respectivamente con su hora (cuando accedio o pasó la tarjeta) , es decir, como si fuese una iteración.

He leído que para iterar dos listas puedo usar el **"zip"** , pero si una tarjeta pasó 2 o más veces y esa es la que quiero dar de baja. Yo puedo eliminar lo que viene siendo el valor de la tarjeta ya que es un numero fijo, pero la hora no , he pensado si puedo eliminarlo por medio de indice pero he encontrado información que a la hora de eliminar un elemento de una lista evidentemente cambias el indice y estoy atorado.

No sé que metodo usar para hacer eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías definir una clase "Pasada" que registre hora y id. Generas una instancia cada vez que se pasa una tarjeta. Las instancias las pones en una lista. Luego puedes recorrer la lista ...

Comment: Gracias por comentarme , la verdad soy nuevo programando en phyton , lo mínimo que he programado es en arduino y referente a clases e instancias es algo que no estoy familiarizado muy bien. Repito gracias .

Answer (score 1):

Solución pythonica:

```
indice = b.index("tres")
a.pop(indice)
b.pop(indice)
```

El método `pop(indice)` extrae el elemento en el índice dado y lo devuelve. La lista queda con un elemento menos.

El método `index(valor)` nos da el índice donde está presente ese valor. Si el valor no está, genera una excepción `ValueError`.

#### Demo

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]

try:
    indice = b.index("tres")
    a.pop(indice)
    b.pop(indice)
    print(a, b)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

produce:

```
[1, 2] ['uno', 'dos']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

He creado este script que te elimina ambos elementos de una lista dandole el nombre de una de ellas.
En este caso, lo he programado para que dandole un nombre de la lista b, elimine el nombre de la lista b y su hora correspondiente.
A ver si te vale:

```
ID=[2,3,5]
HR=[2,4,1]

a=[1,2,3]
b=["uno", "dos", "tres"]

indice= b.index(nombre)
    

def eliminar(posicion):
    a.pop(indice)
    b.pop(indice)


eliminar(indice)
print(a,b)
```

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias , la verdad llevaba como un mes  buscando por youtube , paginas y no encontraba algo claro, me ayudaste en  terminar mí proyecto que era el unico incoveniente que tenía , inclusive mi profesor dijo que no nos ayudaría y creo entender la razón, pero meternos a un lenguaje que no conocemos nada y nos mencionó que apenas aprende. también , me sacó de onda. Repito muchas gracias <3 .

Comment: Un placer, entre todos nos ayudamos. Un saludo

Comment: Explica para que hace el `for`. No entiendo la razón.

Comment: Tienes razon. He planteado mal el ejercicio, no es necesario el for. Con indice=b.index(nombreParametro) se podria resolver mas sencillo

Answer (score 0):

No sé si he entendido correctamente el problema, pero me parece que tener dos listas no es la mejor solución. Si se trata de tener una lista de "ids" y otra con las horas a las que cada uno de esos "ids" se ha registrado, está claro que hay una relación entre ambas listas ¿cuál es esa relación? ¿Usan el mismo índice en ambas? Mantener la coherencia entre ambas listas puede ser complejo, además de poco eficiente al tener que andar iterando o buscando por las listas.

Creo que una solución más simple podría ser tener un diccionario en el que las claves son los "id" de las tarjetas, y los valores son listas con todas las horas a las que el "id" en cuestión se registró.

Por ejemplo:

```
registros = {}

def registrar(id, hora):
  if id in registros:  # Si la tarjeta ya estaba en nuestro diccionario
     registros[id].append(hora) # Añadimos una nueva hora
  else:
     # Si no estaba, creamos una nueva lista para ella, que de momento
     # solo tiene una hora
     registros[id] = [hora]
```

De este modo imagina que se van registrando las siguientes tarjetas:

```
registrar("ID001", "10:30")
registrar("ID002", "10:45")
registrar("ID003", "11:45")
registrar("ID001", "12:30")
registrar("ID002", "12:40")
```

Entonces nuestro diccionario contendrá en este momento la siguiente información:

```
{
 'ID001': ['10:30', '12:30'], 
 'ID002': ['10:45', '12:40'], 
 'ID003': ['11:45']
}
```

En la que se puede ver cómo cada ID queda asociado a una lista con las horas en que fue usado. Algunos IDs tienen dos elementos en esa lista, otros solo tienen uno. Para saber las horas a las que fue usado uno de los IDs basta consultar el diccionario poniendo `registros[id]`, por ejemplo:

```
print(registros["ID001"])
---
['10:30', '12:30']
```

Y eliminar una tarjeta es tan simple como `registros.pop(id)`, lo cual elimina la clave y la lista asociada con ella. Por ejemplo, eliminemos la tarjeta de ID002 y veamos qué queda después en el diccionario:

```
registros.pop("ID002")
print(registros)
---
{
 'ID001': ['10:30', '12:30'],
 'ID003': ['11:45']
}
```